# UFT-ONE 2022 error Object Spy element GUI Desktop

Tags: java, c#, hp-uft

I want to do some testing of Windows desktop applications with UFT 2022 and it doesn't let me see the element tree with the inspector(Object Spy).

With uft 15.02 it does let me, however with 2022 it doesn't show me the tree.

Am I missing some registry, local, variable configuration?

[image]

Comment: What objects are you expecting to see? The question is tagged `Java` and `C#`, is it one of those?

Comment: Hi, Java app in java 6

Comment: Have you verified that the Java Addin is loaded and that the correct options are set in the Record & Run settings dialog?

Comment: Yes, it could be the system environment variables, you have Java 11 natively